# gl.texImage2D under Chromium - does IPC occur

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, webgl, ipc, chromium

gl.texImage2D under Chromium seems to be a lot slower than it's native counterpart. Since chromium uses a multi-process architecture, is it possible that OpenGL is initialized in a different process than the one the JS is executed in, and the call to gl.texImage2D has to go through Chromium's IPC?

What is the explanation for WebGL texImage2D being slower than native glTexImage2D under OpenGL ES 2?

Comment: [WebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp#L3573](https://github.com/yoavweiss/Blink/blob/b3d850543818486ba96f3643bf7c5fcf08ec6a01/Source/core/html/canvas/WebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp#L3573)

Comment: Hello. If the only info you are giving is a pointer to the source code, please make sure it's the right one. This is the implementation that copies a texture from an HTML5 video, the question is general - for a buffer

Comment: This is the line I'm looking for -> https://github.com/yoavweiss/Blink/blob/b3d850543818486ba96f3643bf7c5fcf08ec6a01/Source/core/html/canvas/WebGLRenderingContextBase.cpp#L3343 And it calls another wrapper function. That's why I'm looking for someone with Chromium knowledge explaining the behaviour.

Comment: Well this is why I *commented* it, as a *starting* point for your research. I'm sorry that I didnt made sure that its the exact line you were looking for...

Comment: No problem :) It's just that StackOverflow can provide an in-depth explanation of the behaviours which would take a long time to research manually. After a research through the source code, I found nothing irregular. It seems that the performance of this function is getting improved with each version.Still, I'd appreciate if someone provides an explanation to if the multi-process architecture has any impact on performance of WebGL.